# How to configure workflow runtime (Informatica)?

Tags: workflow, informatica, duration, informatica-powercenter

I would like the workflow to run for 20 minutes....If the running process does not complete within 20 minutes, the workflow should be ended immediately..However, I can only find the timer, but it is used for starting the process after the indicated time which is not I'm looking for...Does anyone know how to specify the duration for the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

[updated to cover complete scenario and cover issues raised by Koushik Sinharoy in comments]

You can achieve it using the timer:

1. Link one to the `Start` task and set it to run for 20 minutes in
   parallel with your session.
2. Have a `Decision task` with `Treat the input links as` set to `OR`. This will trigger the decision whenever any of the preceeding task ends, so either your session will get completed or timer runs out (whatever happens first).
3. Set the `Decision` condition to `$s_your_session.Status = SUCCEEDED`.
4. Link the `Decision task` to `Control Task`.
5. Set `Control task` to `Fail parent`.
6. Add a condition `$Decision.Condition = False` to the link between `Decision task` and `Control task`.

This should be the result:

```
Start--->s_your_session--\
    \                     > Decision [OR] ---(False)---> Control Task [Fail parent]
     \-->timer-----------/
```

Thanks Koushik Sinharoy for the remarks below!

Comment: I dont think this will work. Logic will be, if the workflow completes within 20min, then mark the flow as succeeded and go to next step, if it runs for more than 20min, timer will abort and send notification. Although i can think of polling shell script and not any informatica process. But someone can have a better idea.

Comment: I am sorry Maceiejg, can we mark a workflow as succeeded using     Control Task? I dont think so. But i think you mean to say 'abort' if it completes <20min. So even if the timer is running the workflow can be aborted since main session is complete. I thought about it but some system halts the execution if some flow gets aborted. I think we can use a shell script. My answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257944/how-to-make-timer-task-in-informatica-succeed-after-a-duration/60263238#60263238

Comment: We can Stop the Workflow: https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/workflow-basics-guide/tasks/control-task.html. It will be marked as Stopped.