# How to change session's status from running to succeeded when a condition is met in Informatica?

Tags: unix, timer, informatica

I'm having a problem in changing status of a session from running to succeeded when a condition is met..

For example, I have a workflow as below:

```
start ---------> workA
       |    |---> workB
       |--------> timer_20mins
```

From the diagram above, the process of workA and workB is running concurrently as well as the timer. So if the session's process succeeded before the configured 20 mins in the timer, the status of the timer should change from running to succeeded......I tried with post session success command, but it's still not working. How should I rectify the code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed my previous answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60240964/2834065)?

This problem here is very similar, you just need the decision to fire in case both your sessions are done, so it should have one more decision task with `Treat the input links as` set to `AND` this time.

Briefly, the flow should look like this:

```
Start--->s_sessionA---\
    \                  > Decision [AND]
     \--->s_sessionB--/                \
      \                                 > Decision [OR] ---(False)---> Control Task [Fail parent]
       \-------------->timer-----------/
```